# How can I fix my lined screen on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I was reading my Kindle app when suddenly the screen on my Galaxy 10.1" tablet went blank. The battery was low, so I figured it had just died. I pressed the power button to double check and my screen showed up, except that 3/4 of the screen was black and the rest had streaked lines where the background would be. I can't even do my unlock code because I cannot see it. There has been no water damage to it and it has never been dropped. I have also never altered the coding. I tried charging the battery, powering down and restarting but the screen stays the same. Please, help. Could it be the video card? I have only had it since December.

Update: I attempted a hard reset, but I can't see enough of the screen to continue the prompts. Any suggestions would be helpful.

---

Update: I attempted a hard reset, but I can't see enough of the screen to continue the prompts. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Wait, there are onscreen prompts for a hard reset? That kinda defeats the purpose...

Comment: I have same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue on this particular device. My friend had the same thing happen and was going to give the tablet to me but after doing some research I found that its more than just a software issue.

I'd recommend counting your losses and buying a new tablet. =(